# AngularJS how can this filter be better optimized?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html:

```
    <list>
  <item ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderByPriority | samplesOnly:samples"  type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/customer/{{customer.$id}}">
    <h3>{{customer.name}}</h3>
    </item>
</list>
```

JS:

```
.filter('samplesOnly', function() {

return function(customers, samples) {

    var out = [];
    var samplelist = [];

    angular.forEach(samples, function(sample) {

        if (sample) {
            if (samplelist.indexOf(sample.customerId) == -1) {
                samplelist.push(sample.customerId);
            }
        }

    });

    angular.forEach(customers, function(customer) {

        if (customer.name && samples) {

            if (samplelist.indexOf(customer.$id) == -1) {
                //do not list
            } else {
                out.push(customer)
            }
        }
    });

    return out;
}
```

});

Basically the code sends my customers list and samples list to the view from the controller then through my filter, if there is a sample that has a customer's id associated with it, then the customer gets listed in the html list.

I am brand new to Angular and loving it so far. The above code works fine but it just doesn't feel right. **Is this the proper way to sort that list with Angular?** My gut feeling tells me no.

Comment: Have you tried $filter? Why don't you create a jsfiddle or Plunker so it's faster to give you alternatives

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't use `==` for equalities like that, it's better to use `===`...for indexOf, it's probably not an issue, but remember that `'1' == 1` is true but `'1' === 1` is not.

Comment: Fundamentally there is nothing wrong with what you are doing.  You HAVE to return a new list from a filter.  How you construct it could be optimized slightly, but you really can't get away from iterating through your two lists to determine which ones to include in the new list.  You could come up with something clever to be more efficient, but that doesn't really have anything to do with angular at that point. Your filter is fine.

Comment: Erik, thank you. I just started with the framework and didnt want to go too far doing something out of the norm.

Comment: gonzofish, yea... I dont come from a javascript background... its a little odd to me in some ways.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com